# Find the values of "$p \in \Bbb R$" in which the integral converges:

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, integers

The integral:

$$\int_2^\infty \frac1{\ln(x)^p}\,dx $$

I have no idea on how to find a solution to this. It just seems impossible to have a  solution to this integral in which it converges, however, my teacher insists that it does, even though he refuses to do it himself. Is that true? Then how can I do it?

Comment: You might want to compare it with $\int_k^\infty \frac1x dx$ for $k$ big enough that $\ln(k)^p < k$ (and show that such a $k\ge 2$ exists for each $p$)

Comment: I assume you mean "integral". Edited.

Comment: @Henry so, I have to prove that every p can be be used if k≥2?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: with *asymptotic analysis*:

As for any $p$, we have $\ln^p x=_\infty o(x)$, we also have $\dfrac1x=_{\infty} o\Bigl(\dfrac 1{\ln^p x}\Bigr)$, so if $x$ is large enough,
$$\frac 1{\ln^p x}>\frac 1x.$$